# What is this /(*MARK:A)/ regex feature?

Tags: php, regex

What is the name of this regex feature, and is there any documenation about it (PHP specific or not)?

```
preg_match('/(*MARK:A)a/', 'a', $matches);
```

https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/blob/master/test/Dispatcher/MarkBasedTest.php#L7

Comment: It is tough to search for because "mark" always gets combined with "question".  (And it seems like  `-"question mark"` maybe filters out too much.)

Comment: It's called a marker verb. See https://regex101.com/r/nS7lW7/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the [PCRE pattern documentation](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html), search for "Recording which path was taken" on that page. It appears to be a fairly specific feature and it wouldn't be useful in the example you have provided.

Comment: The example provided is a compatibility test: the only purpose is to figure out if the PHP version that is executing the code supports backtracking control verbs or not; thus it is quite useful, just not in the usual way :P

Comment: Thanks! Seems unfortunate that this will probably still not be easily found via search.

Comment: @machee: I improved the title. It will probably show up eventually in google if you search for "php regex mark" or something.

Comment: ...which it did. Stack must be rubbing some pretty close elbows with Google ;-)